# SQL: select the average value of a column per hour per day for the last 30 days

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table like below which contains temperature data for the last 6 months. It takes about 30-40 readings of temperature in an hour.
'time' is in epoch milliseconds.

| time | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 1678270897857 | 25 |
| 1678270777712 | 30 |
| 1678270657548 | 38 |
| 1678270537402 | 27 |
| 1678270417258 | 38 |
| ... | ... |

I need a query in PostgreSQL to get the 'temperature' averaged per hour per day for the last 30 days (2023-01-15 till 2023-02-15).

So the expected result should look something like:

| date | average_temp |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-15 01:00:00 | 28.5 |
| 2023-01-15 02:00:00 | 32.6 |
| 2023-01-15 03:00:00 | 21.9 |
| ... | ... |
| 2023-01-15 23:00:00 | 33.8 |
| 2023-01-16 00:00:00 | 26.1 |
| 2023-01-16 01:00:00 | 29.4 |
| ... | ... |
| 2023-02-15 22:00:00 | 31.3 |
| 2023-02-15 23:00:00 | 22.7 |

Comment: Which DBMS are you using, MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: So you should remove `mysql` tag of your question

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use below query.

1. Generate time series from `start date` to `end date` by using [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) function, timeframe per each record is 1 hour.
2. Join this time series to your data, then calculate average temperature per each timeframe.

```
WITH date_range AS 
      (SELECT '2023-02-09 00:00:00'::timestamp AS start_date
            , '2023-03-09 23:59:59'::timestamp AS end_date),
     time_series AS
      (SELECT  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t) * 1000 AS start_time, (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t) + 3600) * 1000 AS end_time
       FROM date_range 
            CROSS JOIN generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 hour') t)
       
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(t.end_time/1000) AS date, AVG(d.temperature) AS average_temperature
FROM time_series t
     LEFT JOIN <your table> d ON d.time BETWEEN t.start_time AND t.end_time
GROUP BY t.start_time, t.end_time
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/i4Eqh0ek)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the times to timestamps using to_timestamp then use date_trunc to 'round' to hour.

```sql
CREATE TABLE temp_table(time bigint, temperature INT);

INSERT INTO temp_table(time, temperature)
VALUES (1678270897857,25),
(1678270777712,30),
(1678270657548,38),
(1678270537402,27),
(1678270417258,38);

SELECT date_trunc('hour',to_timestamp(time/1000)) AS date, AVG(temperature) AS avg_temp
FROM temp_table
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

| date | avg_temp |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-08 10:00:00+00 | 31.6000000000000000 |